# How to connect to Elasticsearch using Python Flask

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I'm writing a site on Flask, I decided to make a search system on the site using Elasticsearch, I did it according to the guide https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search .

Here is my code:

```
es = Elasticsearch(os.environ.get('ELASTICSEARCH_URL'))
app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']]) if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None
```

But I get an error:

```
app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']]) if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None
KeyError: 'ELASTICSEARCH_URL'
```

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have simply not degined the elasticsearch key inside your app config. According to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/) you should first make

```py
app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = os.environ.get('ELASTICSEARCH_URL')
```

In the end the app config behaves as a dictionary, and you are trying to access a key that does not exist